# How to construct the query

Tags: php, mysql

I am confused with building the query. I am implementing the search feature in a restaurant site. User first selects the area he is searching for restaurant and then he select the food types like chinese, japanese, thai from the checkboxes.

After selecting all these, the restaurants which providing the selected food in the selected area will be displayed. I am succeeded in getting the pincodes and food types from the yser.

I hav two table with the following fields,

restaurant_dp table with fields

```
id  -ID of the restaurant
pcode -pincode of the area
```

restaurant_iw table with fields

```
id  - id of the restaurant
menu  - menu the restaurant provides (eg., Chinese, thai etc.,)
```

My confusion is how to fetch the records from both the tables with the conditions:

- pcode = Userselectedpincode
- menu = userselected menu

Plz help. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT dp.id FROM restaurant_dp dp INNER JOIN restaurant_iw iw ON dp.id = iw.id WHERE dp.pcode = $pcode AND iw.menu = $menu
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select dp.id
from restaurant_dp dp
inner join restaurant_iw iw on dp.id = iw.id
where dp.pcode = Userselectedpincode 
    and iw.menu = userselectedmenu
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I like to clearly separate relational join clauses from filtering clauses, as I think it improves readbility. It  makes it easy to scan all of the `ON` clauses for proper relationships without the added noise of putting the additional non-relational filtering clauses there.

Comment: Placement in the JOIN vs the WHERE can produce different results

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM restaurant_dp AS dp
LEFT JOIN restaurant_iw AS iw
ON dp.IDrestaurant= iw.IDrestaurant
WHERE dp.pcode = Userselectedpincode 
AND iw.menu = userselectedmenu
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from restaurant_dp dp join restaurant_iw iw on dp.pcode = iw.pcode where dp.pcode = $userselectedpincode and iw.menu = $userselectedmenu;
```

then you just have to make sure that the two variables used in the query are populated properly.

Answer (score 0):

You really should merge these to one table, with all fields relating to a certain restaurant in the same row. If you do that, the query simply becomes `SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE pcode = 'code' AND menu = 'menu';`. Your current setup makes things more difficult, requiring a join:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurant_iw AS iw
LEFT JOIN restaurant_dp AS dp ON iw.id = dp.id
WHERE dp.pcode = 'code' AND iw.menu = 'menu';
```

Comment: I think the idea is that there can be multiple menus per restaurant, thus necessitating two tables to preserve normalization.